# Spring Batch still compatible and usable with Spring Data Neo4j (>= 7.2.1)?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-batch, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

### Initial situation

We are currently facing the challenge of migrating our applications to Spring Boot 3.x across the entire enterprise. Due to the intensive use of Spring Data Neo4j (SDN), a migration to SDN 7.2.1 must be carried out implicitly beforehand, in which the Object Graph Mapper (OGM) is omitted in favor of a renewed Spring Data Neo4j. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/appendix/migrating.html

### Problem

The equally intensively used Spring Batch Framework (spring-boot-starter-batch, 2.7.18) still requires a `SessionFactory` of the Neo4j Object Graph Mapper for the `Neo4jItemReader` and `Neo4jItemWriter`, which, however, no longer exists as intended.

A manually created `CustomNeo4jItemReader` and `CustomNeo4jItemWriter`, in which the previous OGM session (`org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session`) is replaced by direct access to the Neo4j driver, does not work either, as this new driver session (`org.neo4j.driver.Session`) lacks many of the methods used by Spring Batch.

### Target situation

How can we use Spring Batch and Neo4j with **Spring Data Neo4j 7.2.1 and higher** and thus follow the Spring Release Train?

### Versions

- Spring Boot from version 2.7.18
- [Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) from version 7.2.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/appendix/migrating.html)
- Spring Batch 2.7.18 (bundled version of Spring Boot)
- [Spring Batch Extensions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/tree/main/spring-batch-neo4j)

Comment: Based on your question, I had a look at the extensions project and the (Spring Data) Neo4j solution was pretty outdated. Not only version-wise but also regarding the queries within. There is now a PR https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-extensions/pull/125 to use the latest SDN version.